# Get index of base on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li>1</li>
<li class="selected">2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
```

It's easy to get the index if we click on the li, we can do

```
$('li').click(function(){
   alert('index:' + $(this).index()); 
});
```

but what if I want trigger button somewhere else and get the index of selected class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the index of the `li.selected` element when a button is clicked.

In that case, you can get the jQuery object for the `li.selected` element and the call the `index()` method like

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('pre').text($('li.selected').index())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="selected">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
<button>Get Index</button>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: This works but could fail if more than on `li.selected` element on the page. EDIT: OP talks about clicking a button (maybe not relevant to any UL), i was guessing clicking other LI element, so forget my comment :)

Comment: @A.Wolff how about `$('#a ul > li.selected')` ?

Comment: @JenniferAniston Question is do you have unique element LI with class `selected` at specific time? If ya, just use code as provided in this answer

Comment: @JenniferAniston if you can share a updated html structure then we can given a better answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing

```
$('li.selected').index();
```

And on a button click

```
$("button").click(function(){
   alert($('li.selected').index());
});
```